# Weird CMD - VSCode behavior

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmd

yesterday I had SumatraPDF and VisualStudioCode with latex-workshop working with forward and reverse-search. Today the reverse-search didn't work any more. With a simple bat file I tried to show the commandline arguments.

```
echo %* 
pause
```

They seemed correct and when I copied the command and paste it into a new cmd it works. To do further testing I tried to direct command and run it.

```
"C:\....\Code.exe" -g "%1:%2"
pause
```

Visual Studio Code responds: bad option -g

In SumatraPDF I set cmd as command.
Now the behavior is that I have two cmd windows. With the cmd directly opened the VSC open's the file. With the cmd launched indirect I got the error message.

I have tried resetting the environment variables, changing the current working directory, and checking the code page currently in use.

How can it be that cmd behaves differently with seemingly the same environment? And what can I do to make a cmd started from an application work like a cmd started by windows?

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** It appears there were a couple of recent security changes in the way VSCODE.exe is allowed to interact with the command line (especially affecting LaTeX-workshop users) so for recent changes twice this year **see the discussion at** https://forum.sumatrapdfreader.org/t/inverse-search-not-performed-for-vs-code-exe/4486/27

Within SumatraPDF the reverse syntex command for %1 is replaced by %f for file and (l)L for line

It is triggered by a double click near the line of interest and if the synctex index file was compiled correctly by PdfLaTeX (or similar) it will include the tex %f(ilename) and the nearest %l(ine) reference to the point where double clicked.

Thus your tex syctex enhanced "reverse search" call out of SumatraPDF should **historically** be

```
"C:\...path to...\Code.exe" -g "%f:%l"
```

**that's Lower L not 1**
[image]

Avoid using any depreciated -inverse-search parameter from a LaTeX editor just add it **once** into SumatraPDF-settings.txt and then it's not disturbed by repeated assignments when running your `-forward-search`.
It will NOT work if the file.synctex or file.synctex.gz is corrupt by a bad PDF compilation.

**HOWEVER** It seem Microsoft have added the requirement to add a CLI.js handler and requires another switch setting after that ! (see link to discussion in Update above)

For a small test file download https://github.com/GitHubRulesOK/MyNotes/raw/master/AppNotes/SumatraPDF/LATeX%20and%20Reverse-Search.zip unpack and open sync.pdf in SumatraPDF to test that double click on page opens sync.tex in the editor

If the  message is cannot start ... then the command line is not configured correctly. A rough test for a bad synctex is to see what happens if the call is changed by adding `cmd /k echo` to the start, since that will confirm the reverse command. Here I wrote "wrong" as the path to code.exe, once corrected I can remove cmd /k echo.

[image]

For some other systems where the reverse might change
see https://github.com/sumatrapdfreader/sumatrapdf/issues/1197#

However there should be no interference in a valid VsCode call.